# How to add background image and icon to a JSF button?

Tags: css, jsf-2, background-image

I am using JSF 2.0

I am able to add Background image to the JSF button but am not able to add icon to the button.

My Requirement is:- JSF button with Background image and a Icon

Following code am using to add background.

```
     <!-- Discard button-->
        
<h:commandButton action="discard"  style="background-image: url('..\\Images\\leftMenuActiveBg.png');width: 150px;height: 30px;color: white;border-color: white;font-size: 15px; "  value="#{message.discard}">
<rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show" />
 </h:commandButton>
```

Can somebody help me in adding a icon to the button too please.
[image]

I am updating a image for better Explainanation as what I want to achieve and I what I have achieved till now with above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a button with two background images? That's not possible on a single HTML element. The `<h:commandButton>` generates an single HTML `<input type="submit">` element, while you basically need a `<button type="submit" class="background"><span class="icon">` instead. You'd need to create a custom component which generates exactly that HTML, or to adopt a 3rd party component librarty which has such a component in its set, such as [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org). See also [the `<p:commandButton>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf).

Comment: Hey BalusC: I guess you have misunderstood the question, or might be my framing migth have been poor. For better exmplaination I have attached the Image. I hope with this you will be able to help me in a better way.Eagerly looking for the reply.

Comment: What exactly does `leftMenuActiveBg.png` contain? It contains the icon, right?

Comment: No it contains Background Image, the blue one. Now over it I am required to add icon. The background image and icon are two different image.

Comment: Can we achieve the same in Richfaces, its very important, please guide.

Comment: No, it doesn't have such a component. Importance is irrelevant to me, please don't put pressure on volunteers, this is pretty rude.